# rails habtm single category model but populate and filter by two select box in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

okay, if you have a habtm relationship between category and articles, now through the category index page is it possible to perform a filter, using two select box populated with the categories, which shows articles belonging to either or both category?

this is how i tried.

category controller

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all
end

def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:name][:id])
end
```

category index page

```
<%= form_for :categories, :url => {:action => :show}, :method => "get" do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= collection_select(:name, :id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= collection_select(:name, :id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

category show page

```
<ul>
  <% @category.articles.each do |a| %>
    <li><%= a.author %></li>
    <li><%= a.title%></li>
    <li><%= a.pub_date%></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

at this stage it only presents articles, based on the second collection_select.

also, is habtm altogether necessary to do something like this? can this be done if there is a column instead in the articles model? which is the best way?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to rename the second collection_select ids and try a Where clause with OR in your controller. Something like that:

```
def index
    @categories = Category.all
end

def show
    @category = Category.where(:id => [params[:name][:id1], params[:name][:id2]])
end
```

and in your index page:

```
<%= form_for :categories, :url => {:action => :show}, :method => "get" do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :category %><br />
      <%= collection_select(:name, :id, Category.all, :id1, :name) %>
    </div>
      <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :category %><br />
      <%= collection_select(:name, :id, Category.all, :id2, :name) %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I did not test it, but this is the idea.

Hope it helps

Comment: hey thanks for this, but it did not help. rather i tried changing the first id's and then it worked.